# do PHP's array functions use memory addresses to iterate over the array items

Tags: php, arrays, memory-management, memory-address

I have heard someone say that using php's array functions - such as `array_filter` to filter/choose some elements from an array is better than using a foreach.

The reason for this would be the fact that under the hood, the said php functions use memory addressing vs doing themselves a 'for each' or a 'normal' iteration over all elements.

I'm unable to find any information about this, and looking at the [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L5254) does not provide any conclussive information to me.

Are they more efficient?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php   at low levels, it's all memory addresses. none of that is ever exposed to higher level code, particularly at the actual "php script" level.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please help by accepting it :).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, objects are allocated automatically, when needed, and garbage collected when they are no longer useable, and it all happens without the intervention of the PHP programmer.

It's perhaps of some interest to observe that PHP is itself written in C! the nitty gritty of memory management is written in C, which provides the tools needed to do that kind of thing, so that the language created, doesn't require the programmer to do much themselves.

Although PHP can be sophisticated in implementation, it was not designed for robust computing.